# How to regenerate keys of deployments in Azure AI Studio

Tags: azure-openai, azure-ai

I have deployed some OpenAI models in Azure AI Studio. I want to regenerate the keys but I don't see an option to do so. Is it possible to regenerate keys of models in Azure AI Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default resources used in an Azure AI Studio are based on an "Azure AI services" resource in Azure.

AI Studio capture from "Manage" menu, after clicking on my Azure AI resource:
[image: Azure AI resource detail]

If I click on "Default_AzureOpenAI", I can clearly see the underlying resource:
[image: openai resource]

And no, there is no button to renegerate key.

You can do it:

- From the Azure portal, by clicking on the "Azure AI services" resource:
  [image: portal view]
  Then "Keys and Endpoint tab" where you will see "Regenerate key1" and "Regenerate key2" buttons:
  [image: buttons]
- From the az cli: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cognitiveservices/account/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cognitiveservices-account-keys-regenerate
- From the REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/accountmanagement/accounts/regenerate-key?view=rest-cognitiveservices-accountmanagement-2023-05-01&tabs=HTTP

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to regenerate keys of models in azure ai studio?

Not in AI Studio but you should be able to do it in your Azure OpenAI service.

Just go to `Keys and Endpoint` under `Resource Management` and you should be able to regenerate the keys.

[image]

BTW, the keys are not per model deployment. They are at the service level and apply to all model deployments in a service.